# Spring Cloud Data Flow long term support and maintenance roadmap

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, lts

We are in the process of building a new interoperability platform for our company, and we're looking into several data integration platforms as potential foundation candidates. One of these candidates is Spring Cloud Data Flow.

We would like to know if there's a long term support for this platform and/or a maintenance plan for the upcoming years.

We weren't able to find clear answers anywhere, and we would appreciate greatly if anyone here would provide us with some sort of answer ?

Any links are helpful. Thank you !

Comment: Did you see the support page of the project? https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow#support 

Currently End of Support for the latest version is 2023-10-12.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link, I stumbled on it before. It seems there's no LTS support even for commercial versions, unlike some other solutions.  Is there any guarantee of safe upgrade to newer versions every time, or maybe just assurance of continues upgrade of SCDF ?